# Looking for dates and making calculations in an Excel array

Tags: excel

I have been looking for any way to do this, without luck, so i'm begging for your help:

I have two tables in Excel, the first like this:
`ID     Date                Quantity    Km 
 1      02/01/2016 13:45    100         300
 2      05/02/2016 12:54    150         350
 3      03/01/2016 14:16    125         250`
(the dates are in spanish format, not english, and i'm using a spanish version of Excel)

And the second like this:
`Month     Indicator
 January        X
 February       X`

I need to "search" in the first table the rows corresponding to every month, divide the Km between the Quantity (of every row), and then calculate the average of the results.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use array formula (that is you need to press `ctrl + shift + enter`)

```
=SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!Date,"mmmm")=A2,sheet1!Quantity,0))/SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!Date,"mmmm")=A2,sheet1!Km,0))
```

If the DIV/0 error bothers you, try this array formula

```
=IF(SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!Date,"mmmm")=A9,sheet1!Km,0))=0,0,SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!Date,"mmmm")=A9,sheet1!Quantity,0))/SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!Date,"mmmm")=A9,sheet1!Km,0)))
```

Comment: I don't understand your example very well. Using the table i wrote as example it would stay like that: `=SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!B:B,"mmmm")=A2,sheet1!C:C,0))/SUM(IF(TEXT(sheet1!B:B,"mmmm")=A2,sheet1!D:D,0))`  but what do you reder with **A2**?

Comment: `A2` is the cell in sheet2, the value = January.